# Fantasy book about a human female guard raised by feline race and whose commander has wings

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for this book series. I can't really remember details but I think there were four races in the books and one race had tentacles on their heads which they used to communicate; they were also a very insular race.

I'd be glad for the help.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180362/fantasy-book-ya-girl-with-magical-powers-tattoos (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

The [*Chronicles of Elantra*](http://msagarawest.wordpress.com/bibliography/chronicles-of-elantra/) series by [Michelle Sagara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelle_Sagara).

Comment: And published by Luna. A good series I think.

Comment: @Gilles, thank you for adding the links. I was on my phone at the time and having trouble even switching web pages to double-check the series title and author!