# Fantasy book, YA, Girl with magical powers & tattoos

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read this book series in middle school. I believe that it would be classified as young adult fiction/fantasy. A girl has magical powers, and with her growing powers comes runes/tattoos in her arms. This is shown on every book cover. I know that one cover is blue. This one shows the girl in a black tank top and black pants. One is a yellow cover, with her in a dress (I think). 
The girl has a friend/mentor, who she develops feelings for.
The girl is the key to stopping a war between multiple factions/people. Each side is trying to use her to their advantage.
I think the series was written in the early 2000s.

Comment: We could likely use some more details, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details

Comment: Thanks. I went back and added everything that I can think of. I’ll edit as I remember things.

Comment: Awesome! I'm sure one of the 'experts' will be around soon.

Comment: You might check [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176573/30870) and the question it links.  Of course, this description would also match the **Mortal Instruments**.

Comment: youre talking about the House of night series

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Totally just answered my own question. I remembered that the author’s name is Michelle Sagara. Looked up books, and the series is the *[Elantra](https://michellesagara.com/series/chronicles_of_elantra/)* series.

> These follow the adventures of Private Kaylin Neya, a young woman who serves the Hawks in the towering Halls of Law. She’s Elantra’s version of a police officer, a mortal in a city ruled by Dragons.

Some of the covers showing the tattoos:
[image: Cast in Shadow] [image: Cast in Courtlight] [image: Cast in Secret]