# Fantasy book YA girl investigates deaths in the slums

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I think the girl was part of a crime investigation team? I think there are avians and shapeshifters? Or those are the name of their departments? The girl gets called to investigate mysterious deaths where kids/people die after marks or words suddenly appears on their body. I think the girl also had those marks on her before? I can’t remember.

Answer (score 7):

That's Michelle Sagara's [*Cast in Shadow*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9542.Cast_in_Shadow?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=qvNY088dJP&rank=1)

Book summary (emphasis mine):

> Seven years ago Kaylin fled the **crime-riddled streets of Nightshade**, knowing that something was after her. **Children were being murdered — and all had the same odd markings** that mysteriously appeared on her own skin...
>
> Since then, she's learned to read, she's learned to fight and she's become one of the vaunted **Hawks who patrol and police** the City of Elantra. Alongside the **winged Aerians** and immortal Barrani, she's made a place for herself, far from the mean streets of her birth.
>
> But children are once again dying, and a dark and familiar pattern is emerging, Kaylin is ordered back into Nightshade with a partner she knows she can't trust, a Dragon lord for a companion and a device to contain her powers — powers that no other human has. Her task is simple — find the killer, stop the murders... and survive the attentions of those who claim to be her allies!)

Comment: If this is correct, it will be marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180362/fantasy-book-ya-girl-with-magical-powers-tattoos).  This is mainly the mechanism on this site to link questions about the same work.